# Why jest.spyOn doesn't invalidate module cache when requiring single function?

Tags: javascript, caching, jestjs, requirejs

I have

```
// mod1.js
const f = (_n) => console.info('a:', _n) || _n * 2
module.exports = { f }
```

```
// mod2.js
const { f } = require('./mod1')
const g = (_n) => 3 * f(_n)
module.exports = { g }
```

and a test file

```
describe('mod2', () => {
    it('should check 1', () => {
        const { g } = require('../src/mod2')
        expect(g(2)).toEqual(12)
    })

    it('should check 2', () => {
        const mod1 = require('../src/mod1')
        jest.spyOn(mod1, 'f').mockImplementation(_n => _n * 4)
        const { g } = require('../src/mod2')
        expect(g(2)).toEqual(24)
    })

    it('should check 3', () => {
        const mod1 = require('../src/mod1')
        jest.spyOn(mod1, 'f').mockImplementation(_n => _n * 5)
        const { g } = require('../src/mod2')
        expect(g(2)).toEqual(30)
    })
})
```

Well, second and third test fail because apparently the original function (loaded by the first test) is used.

If I have

```
// mod2.js
const mod1 = require('./mod1')
const g = (_n) => 3 * mod1.f(_n)
module.exports = { g }
```

all is good!

You can check this repo: https://github.com/oliviera9/test-jest-require-cache

Comment: Because you're not mocking a module, but just mocking an object method.

Comment: But then, what's happening? is this related to jest or node module caching?

Comment: *mod2.js* is calling `f`, the local variable that was destructured from the *mod1.js* module object **once**, when the code was executed. Move the property access inside the `g` function and it'll work

Comment: So the problem is `g` which uses the first `f` loaded when compiling the module, and that reference does not change.